# Django , password dont match error message not displaying. Customised UserAuth app

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-authentication

I am having issues with an error being "not raised" within a register form page. It seems to pulling the form again but without "passwords do not matched" message.

my form handler code

```
from django import forms 

from accounts.models import User

class RegistrationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """
    Form for registering a new account.
"""
email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput,label="Email")
password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label="Password")
password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                            label="Password (again)")

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['email', 'password1', 'password2']

def clean(self):
    """
    Verifies that the values entered into the password fields match

    NOTE: Errors here will appear in ``non_field_errors()`` because it applies to more than one field.
    """
    cleaned_data = super(RegistrationForm, self).clean()
    if 'password1' in self.cleaned_data and 'password2' in self.cleaned_data:
        if self.cleaned_data['password1'] != self.cleaned_data['password2']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match. Please enter both fields again.")
    return self.cleaned_data

def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
    user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
    if commit:
        user.save()
    return user
```

my views code:

```
def register(request):
"""
User registration view.
"""
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.save()
        return redirect('/')
else:
    form = RegistrationForm()
return render_to_response('accounts/register.html', {
    'form': form,
}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I setup the register to be in the root of the app '/'

patterns in account app

from django.conf.urls import url
   from accounts import views

```
 urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^$', views.register, name='register'),
  #url(r'^register$', views.register, name='register'),
  url(r'^login$', views.login, name='login'),
  url(r'^logout$', views.logout, name='logout'),

]
```

in main:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls', namespace='accounts')),

    # sets login/register to root url
    url(r'^', include('accounts.urls', namespace ='accounts')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
```

]

The accounts app sets the username to be an email for djangos built in userAuth. All other fields fill in on the html page such as "invalid email address"

I have tried multiple things but have failed so far, any help would be appreciated at this stage.

Thank you.

I am using ubuntu 14, python 3.4 django 1.8, virtualenv

Comment: Just to clarify, when you post a form with two passwords which do not match, Django still successfully registers the user? Or does it not register the user, redirect to '/' and not raise any errors either?

Comment: no registration occurs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using:

```
raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match...')
```

so this is a global error; it won't show next to a specific field. Make sure that your template `accounts/register.html` show these errors.

---

Also just to make sure; you can `print` something just before that `raise` (just for debugging) so you can confirm that the validation occurred in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

**Use This Code to registration/signup.html**

```
{% if form.errors %}
{% for field in form %}
{% for error in field.errors %}
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
{% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
 <div class="alert alert-danger">
 <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```